# cant pass multiple models to my DetailsView using generic views

Tags: python, django

I have tried passing Album objects and song objects to my DetailView trying to get the DetailView working with both Album models and Song model. But anytime I try deleting a song my code cant seem to get the Song.objects.all(). I get a cannot find a song object in query or something like that

here are my url patterns:

```
urlpatterns =

     [
      /music/
      url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

    # /music/album_id/
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

    url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),

    url(r'album/add/$', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='album-add'),

    #/music/album/2/
    url(r'album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.AlbumUpdate.as_view(), name='album-update'),

    #/music/album/add/delete/
    url(r'^album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.AlbumDelete.as_view(), name='album-delete'),

    #/music/album/album_id/add-song/
    url(r'^album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/add-song/$', views.SongView.as_view(), name='song-add'),

    # /music/album_id/song/delete/
    url(r'^album/song/delete/(?P<song_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.SongDelete.as_view(), name='song-delete'),
```

views.py:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'music/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_albums'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.all()

class  DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'music/detail.html'
    model =  [Album, Song]
    # context_object_name = 'all_songs'

    def get_object(self, queryset=Song.objects.all()):
        return queryset

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.all()

class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist','album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']

class AlbumUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist','album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']

class AlbumDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Album
    success_url = reverse_lazy('music:index')

class UserFormView(generic.View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name='music/registration_form.html'

    #displays a blank form
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.GET)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    #process form data
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save(commit=False)
        #cleand (Normalized) data
            username= form.cleaned_data['username']
            password=form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
    #Returns user object if cresentials are correct

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('music:index')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

class SongView(CreateView):
    # template_name = 'music/song_form.html'
    model = Song
    fields= ['title', 'album', 'audio_file', 'favorite']

class SongDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Song
    success_url = reverse_lazy('music:detail')
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Album(models.Model):
    artist=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo=models.FileField()


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return  reverse('music:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + '_' + self.artist

class Song(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album=models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    audio_file= models.FileField()
    favorite=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return  reverse('music:detail' , kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

please need help, been o this for a while now **wheww

Comment: Sorry, it's really not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman two things>>> 1. I am trying to delete a song object(instance) using generic DeleteView and use reverse_lazy for the success_url which is suppose to be the details page i.e DetailView.... but my details page (DetailView) in the Html needs both the Album object and the Song.objects.all() to display both album field and song fields, 2. if I define a query_set or get_context_object for Song.objects.all() in my DetailView I get errors saying 'cannot  find song in query set''

Answer (score 2):

If you need all songs in your DetailView you should pass them in the context; they are completely separate from the queryset of Albums you need to use to find the current object.

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'music/detail.html'
    model = Album

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['all_songs'] = Song.objects.all()
        return context
```

(In future, please also post only relevant code and ensure that your indentation is correct.)